# Access token validation failure. Invalid audience error when accessing revokeSignInSessions Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying this call from postman with a valid access token - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/xyz@abc.com/revokeSignInSessions

I have double checked on the credentials part and we have given User.ReadWrite.All

But still i am getting this error

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
> "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2024-02-27T18:03:57",
> "request-id": "***",
> "client-request-id": "***"
> }
> } }

Comment: If you parse the token at https://jwt.ms, does the audience header look right?

Answer (score 0):

I had a test in my side, first of all, your [url must be wrong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId_or_userPrincipleName/revokeSignInSessions`, you missed `/users`.

But missing it would cause `Resource not found for the segment` error.

[image]

Pls make sure you are using correct method for generate access token, using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) as a sample. By the way, this API only supports `Delegated (work or school account)`, but you are using `xyz@abc.com` in your request which I'm not sure if it's a personal account.

Url below is an example for gathering auth code before generating access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_name/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=client_id 
&response_type=code 
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F 
&response_mode=query 
&scope=profile email openid offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

Comment: We have tried with this scope. but even then it was not working after changing the scope. we are still getting the same error

Comment: could you please share how we generate the access token?